# Missing Access Rights for OpenOffice Applications

Tags: sudo, 18.04, openoffice.org

I'm very new to Linux and Ubuntu.

I recently installed Ubuntu LTS 18.04 and I've replaced LibreOffice with OpenOffice, but I'm not sure how to allow myself to access OpenOffice without relying on the sudo command.

Is there a way to make it open like any other program?

My computer gives me an error when I try to run it from the console without sudo.

It says, "OpenOffice user installation cannot be processed due to missing access rights. Please make sure that you have sufficient access rights for the following location and restart OpenOffice: /home/userName/.openoffice/4".

Here is what the command "namei -lx ~/.openoffice/4" brings up. I have replaced my username (which is my real name) with "userName".

> f: /home/userName/.openoffice/4
>   Drwxr-xr-x root   root   /
>   drwxr-xr-x root   root   home
>   drwxr-xr-x userName userName userName
>   drwxr-xr-x root   root   .openoffice
>   drwxr-xr-x root   root   4

Comment: How did you do install OpenOffice?

Comment: @muru I used the instructions here: https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-openoffice-on-ubuntu-debian/

Comment: Did you, at any point, run OpenOffice as root? Add the output of `namei -lx ~/.openoffice/4` to the question, please.

Comment: @muru I'm not sure what you mean by root. I don't think so.